# Access operation and read/write. What is a difference?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

[image]

What is a difference between an access operation and read/write operation? I was convinced that read/write = access. Please explain.

This slide comes from http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/Dagstuhl.pdf

Comment: Why the image (instead of text)? What makes that even worse is that the original source is a PDF, so you could easily have just copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same thing.  The access operations on a volatile variable are reads and writes.

In the JLS (17.4.2) they use slightly different terminology.  The *Actions* that are relevant to the JMM model are listed as *Read*, *Write*, *Volatile read*, Volatile *write*, and so on.  (The reason for using different terms is to allow greater precision in the specification.)